# Redux-persist not persisting quantity, but still persisting cart total?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-persist

I’m trying to persist the state of a shopping cart (items, quantity of each said item, subtotal, and total). I am using `redux-persist` for this.

My issue is that when I change the quantity of items in the cart (ex. from 1 to a qty of 5), then refresh the page, the quantity will go back down to 1. The subtotal and total still reflect the price x 5 of said item. The quantity can’t be changed after the refresh, and if I keep trying to increase the quantity, the cart subtotal and total still increase.

The quantity also doesn’t change in Chrome DevTools (under the Application, Storage > Local Storage tab), so I don't think it's a display issue.

I have tried `whitelisting`/`blacklisting` certain states in my `configureStore.js` file. I don’t think it’s a problem with the `redux-persist` package—I believe it’s a problem with how I’m implementing it, or how my store is set up.

**How can I have the items, quantity of each item, and subtotal/total persisted for my shopping cart? More importantly, I’m concerned about the quantity of items and the cart subtotal and total staying in sync.**

I have uploaded my code to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/j-michaels/redux-co), so you can see everything and how it all interacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with `redux-persist`, it's that there's a bug in your  `ADD_QUANTITY` reducer.

It currently looks like this:

```
if (action.type === ADD_QUANTITY) {
        let addedItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === action.id);
        addedItem.quantity += 1;
        let newSubTotal = state.subTotal + addedItem.price;
        return {
            ...state,
            subTotal: newSubTotal,
            cartTotal: newSubTotal + shippingCost
        }

    }
```

So this action finds the item from the list of all the available items, then increments its quantity (by mutating the original object, which isn't best practice but not the problem here) and calculates a new subtotal. Then it does nothing with the updated item.

As you have already added your item to the `addedItems` array in your state, you need to find it there and update a copy of *that* version of it, and then return this updated list as your new `addedItems` array:

```
if (action.type === ADD_QUANTITY) {
    const addedItem = state.addedItems.find(item => item.id === action.id);
    let newSubTotal = state.subTotal + addedItem.price;
    const updatedItems = state.addedItems.map(item =>
      item.id === action.id ? { ...item, quantity: item.quantity + 1 } : item
    );
    return {
      ...state,
      addedItems: updatedItems,
      subTotal: newSubTotal,
      cartTotal: newSubTotal + shippingCost
    };
  }
```

Comment: I’ve implemented your solution, and did something similar for the `MINUS_QUANTITY` action as well. Now it seems to be working as it should. Thank you for the guidance!